# swi-prolog error due to single quote in assert

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

I while trying to assert fact with single quote `'`, swi-prolog gives this error:

```
raise PrologError("".join(["Caused by: '", query, "'."]))
pyswip.prolog.PrologError: Caused by: 'assertz((fact('kh'an'))).'.
```

This is python snippet where error occurs:

```
linkage = "linkage('"+str(read_str.lower())+"', '"+ str(sub_link) +"')"
self.prolog_rule_identify.assertz(linkage)
```

for `read_str` as `today's date`, `Men's wear` etc

Comment: Try using `\'` instead of `'`. Like so: `Men\'s wear`

Comment: @vmg: needs better solution, that way requires to modify user input which is not advisable for me

Comment: Why not? Simply check the string for `'` and replace it. You can do that in python with replace(). The `'` character has special meaning for the definition of atoms, you can't use special characters within an atom without appropriated escape sequences.

Comment: `linkage = "linkage('"+str(read_str.replace('\'','\\\'').lower())+"', '"+ str(sub_link) +"')"`

Comment: @vmg,can you please explain by `'\'','\\\''`, initially I was thought just replacing any `'` character in string with `\'`. Though you have done the same, could you please elaborate

Comment: Sure. What I did was exactly what you described. The thing is, the backslash (\\) character is used to determine escape sequences in both Python and Prolog (and many other programming languages). Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html) and [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=charescapes). In particular, \' translates to the literal ' and \\ translates to \.